# Is there a way to prevent saved authentication in Tortoise SVN at the Server level?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN and I am trying to not have username/password stored.
I was able to fix figure out that if I make changes to %appdata%\Subversion\config
enabling: (but this is at the user level)
`store-passwords = no`
`store-auth-creds = no`

I would like to apply this but at the server level how can I do that?
When I make the same changes to the servers.config file;
%appdata%\Subversion\servers
The changes would not apply, Any reason why or am I missing a step here.

Apply the changes below in the servers.config file
`store-passwords = no`
`store-auth-creds = no`

To apply this changes at the server level so that any user that try to save their credentials with Tortoise SVN and disable the save option for all users

Comment: Why do you want to disable password caching on client side? What authentication method do you use with your SVN server?

Comment: I am using the store-plaintext-passwords Authentication

Comment: So you want to configure your server in a way that it enforces a certain configuration on the client? Is my understanding correct? I would think this contradicts the client-server paradigm.